# Controlling the scope in a Kotlin DSL builder

Tags: kotlin, scope, dsl, builder

I try to find the perfect solution to my scope problem, and I would really like your opinions.

I have some third party classes that I cannot change :

```
class Employee {
    var id = 0
    var name = ""
    var card : Card? = null
    // ...
}

class Card {
    var cardId = 0
}
```

My goal is to be able to build an Employee like this :

```
val built = employee {
     id = 5
     name = "max"
     addCard {
          cardId = 5
     }
}
```

There is no method **addCard** in the original beans.
Therefore I came up with the following builder:

```
@DslMarker
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
annotation class Scoped

@Scoped
object Builder {
    inline fun employee (init: (@Scoped Employee).() -> Unit): Employee {
        val e = Employee()
        e.init()
        return e
    }

    inline fun Employee.addCard(init: (@Scoped Card).() -> Unit) {
        val c = Card()
        c.init()
        card = c
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, now I get the infamous error :

> error: 'inline fun Employee.addCard(init: (Scratch_1.Card).() -> Unit): Unit' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary

I understand the cause of the error and I would like to think about the solutions.

1. Remove the DSLMarker annotation to be able to inherit the parent scope. Unfortunately, this allows illegal builder usage :

   ```
   with(Builder) {
           val built = employee {
               id = 5
               name = "max"
               addCard {
                   employee {
                     // ...
                   }
               cardId = 5
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the qualified this to access to parent scope. But then we have to use another qualified this to get the proper receiver. This is pretty verbose.

   ```
   with(Builder) {
           val built = employee {
               id = 5
               name = "max"
               with(this@with) {
                   this@employee.addCard {
                       cardId = 5
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ```
3. Inherit the employee to be able to put the extension function in it (delegation is not a possibility here because I have a lot of properties in Employee, and there are not all defined by an interface).
   This could not always work if the third party class is final.

   ```
   class EmployeeEx : Employee() {
       inline fun addCard(init: (@Scoped Card).() -> Unit) {
           val c = Card()
           c.init()
           card = c
      }
   }
   ```

   and the builder :

   ```
   @Scoped
   object Builder {
       inline fun employee (init: (@Scoped EmployeeEx).() -> Unit): Employee {
           val e = EmployeeEx()
           e.init()
           return e
       }
   }
   ```

---

So what is the best solution ? Am I missing something ?
Thanks a lot for reading all this !

Answer (score 2):

1. You can define [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) without begetting new class,
   it works for foreign untouchable sources as well:

```
@DslMarker
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
annotation class Scoped

@Scoped
object Builder {
    inline fun employee(init: (@Scoped Employee).() -> Unit) = Employee().apply(init)
}

fun Employee.addCard(init: (@Scoped Card).() -> Unit) = run { card = Card().apply(init) }
```

2. There are two classical tools to control dsl scope:

   - `@DSLMarker` for achievable code, as you are using, and
   - `@Deprecated (level = ERROR)` for all other cases where the first approach does not work.

For example, currently you can construct embedded employees:

```
val built = employee {
       id = 5
       name = "max"
       addCard {
           cardId = 6
       }
       employee {  }  // <--- compilable, but does not have sense
   }
```

And you can directly forbid this by means of deprecation:

```
@Deprecated(level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR, message = "No subcontractors, please.")
fun Employee.employee(init: (@Scoped Employee).() -> Unit) = Unit
```

Now the following sample is not compilable:

```
 val built = employee {
        //...
        employee {  }  // <--- compilation error with your message
    }
```

3. You may find this useful: [Kotlin DSL example](https://github.com/ivan-osipov/kotlin-dsl-example)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer !

Some comments :

1. It works but then my extension method is visible globally. One has just to import it to use it. I cannot enforce that it will be used only with this builder.
2. I though that the DSLMarker had replaced the @Deprecated annotation. I did not now both could work it parallel. It could be the solution.
3. The repository is interesting but he faces the same issue as I do :)

    teacher {
                    teacher {
                         // wrong !
                    }
                    subjectIndexes(0, 1)

Comment: Nicolas, can you please share the precise version of _kotlin_ language you use? Extension function to A can officially be declared as a member of B, just like you do in the original example - and this original example works for me perfectly (both inline and not) - no problem to be called with the implicit receiver. I'd like to reproduce your error.

Comment: We use Kotlin 1.3.11.
You mean with the code I gave for the builder, you don't get the error in yellow ?
Are you sure you put the DslMarker annotation ?

Comment: I am sure: a precise copy of your code does not fire yellow error in my environment. Further, I can use the `built` employee in the code - it contains all declared pieces. `KotlinVersion.CURRENT` says I'm using 1.3.10.

Comment: I think we are not talking about same code. I put the example with error here : https://pl.kotl.in/wZ8dvca4G
This code is failing with latest version but also with 1.3.10.

Comment: I've found the difference: in the original sample, you didn't mention `with(Builder)` clause. Without it the code is workable:  https://pl.kotl.in/Hy_WSOiGZ

Comment: But then if you don't have the `with` you can write something that makes no sense  like : https://pl.kotl.in/sC7U5eLOm
Notice the double `employe`. The builder object is not here to protect you !

Answer (score 1):

I'd offer the following design, it's quite classic and the resulting code is short.

1. As `Builder` adds additional scope and prevents us from ugly imports, we just stop using it by `with` construction and overload `invoke` operator instead.
2. Use both `@DslMarker` for editable code and `@Deprecated` for foreign one to control the scope

```
@Scoped
object builder {
    operator fun invoke(init: BuildingContext.() -> Unit) = BuildingContext().init()
}

@Scoped
class BuildingContext {
    fun employee(init: Employee.() -> Unit) = Employee().apply { init() }

    fun Employee.addCard(init: Card.() -> Unit) = run {card = Card().apply { init() }}

    @Deprecated(level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR, message = "Employee is forbidden here.")
    fun Employee.employee(init: (@Scoped Employee).() -> Unit) { }

    @Deprecated(level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR, message = "Card is forbidden here.")
    fun Card.addCard(init: (@Scoped Card).() -> Unit) { }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    builder {
        val crafted = employee {
            //employee {}  <-- deprecated, causes compilation error
            id = 5
            name = "max"
            addCard {
                // addCard {} <-- deprecated too
                cardId = 7
            }
        }
        println(crafted.card?.cardId)
    }
}
```

The full version works here: https://pl.kotl.in/ICLYZyetU

Comment: Interesting solution but IMHO not really practical...
If you have a deep dsl hierarchy with several extension functions, you do not want to clutter your code with all possible wrong combinations....

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I have now a good overview.

First I thought the cause of the problem was the IScoped on the builder object. When removing it, it works.
However it stills allows "illegal" syntax :

```
val built = employe {
        id = 5
        name = "max"
        addCard {
            employe {

            }
            cardId = 5
        }
    }
```

**The solution**

Only keep extension methods in you builder object and don't put annotation on the later.

In my case, I have to introduce another builder to start the construction

```
object EmployeBuilder {   
}

object Builder {
    inline fun EmployeBuilder.employe(init: (@Scoped Employee).() -> Unit): Employee {
        val e = Employee()
        e.init()
        return e
    }

    inline fun Employee.addCard(init: (@Scoped Card).() -> Unit) {
        val c = Card()
        c.init()
        card = c
    }

 }

 fun main() {
    with(Builder) {
        val built = EmployeBuilder.employe {
            id = 5
            name = "max"
            addCard {
                cardId = 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now we have it :

1. no "pollution" of the class contexts because the extension methods are only available within the builder object.
2. No illegal syntax can be used because all the parameters are locked with the DslMarker annotation.